# Find combination of products for max profit

Tags: algorithm, statistics

I have a problem where I have to find out the best combination of products which can yield maximum profit.

Suppose I have 3 products (A,B and C). The Unit cost of each product respectively is ($a, $b and $c). The inflation rate for A,B and C is (p%, q% and r%) i.e. every time user purchase a product, its unit cost increases by the said inflation rate.  User can only purchase the product in lot of (l,m and n) quantities respectively. Each product gives a profit of $x, $y and $z respectively per unit.

So for a single round of purchase, for product A,

- Total Cost = l*$a
- Total Profit = l*$x
- Unit price after purchase = ((p/100)*$a)+$a

How can I find the right combination of purchase of A,B and C, which will give me maximum profit.

I referred internet and found something called "Optimal Product Mix" problem given here...

http://www.technicalcommunicationcenter.com/2013/03/29/how-to-calculate-optimal-product-mix-with-ms-excel-2010-solver-to-maximize-profits/

However, somehow I am not able to relate it which my problem statement.

Can someone suggest me a way to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your budget is significantly larger than the price of a single lot, a greedy algorithm should get you close to an optimal solution - iteratively select the lot that you can afford that gives you the most profit right now until all options are no longer profitable.

If your budget is not significantly larger than a single lot, or you must solve for *the* globally optimal solution, this reduces to the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

If your budget is unlimited, simply buy enough lots of each item to make the profit go negative, then stop - the greedy algorithm will lead to the same result.